# Sampling an IObservable with ReactiveCommand

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

It is often the case that a `ReactiveCommand` must act upon data in the UI which can be fitted into an `IObservable`. Every time the command fires it should sample the data source and act upon it.

```
IObservable<CommandContext> context = ... ;
Command = ReactiveCommand.Create();
context.Sample(Command).Subscribe(c => CommandImpl(c));
```

The snag is that `Sample` will not resample when context does not change. I tried to fix this using `Repeat`, but due to Rx being pushy instead of lazy it results in a lockup.

```
contextSelect(c => Observable.Repeat(c)).Switch()
    .Sample(Command)
    .Subscribe(c => CommandImpl(c));
```

Comment: The data in the UI should be bound to properties of your VM (normal properties or `ObservableAsPropertyHelper`s). So why do you need the `context` stream, when you can simply access current values of such properties inside your `CommandImpl`? (In other words, isn't it the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?)

Comment: The context stream can be bound to the viewmodel, using ReactiveUI like `this.WhenAny(v => v.PropertyX)`. In other cases the observable may be coming out of a service layer. The thing is that I want this to work stateless. Introducing local variables or properties to store such values are a hacky workaround in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a `WithLatestFrom()` method. [It is available in many Rx flavors](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html), but sadly not in the latest official version of Rx.NET (2.2.5).

If you had it, your code could look like this:

```
Command
   .WithLatestFrom(context, (_, ctx) => ctx))
   .Subscribe(ctx => CommandImpl(ctx));
```

Fortunately, this operator [appears to be added](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/90) to the [latest prerelease package of Rx.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/2.3.0-beta2) (2.3.0-beta2).

Alternatively, you can use one of the implementations provided in the github issue linked above - e.g. [this one by James World](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/90#issuecomment-92409645) (note - I didn't test it):

```
public static IObservable<TResult> WithLatestFrom<TLeft, TRight, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TLeft> source,
    IObservable<TRight> other,
    Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return other.Publish(os =>
        source.SkipUntil(os)
              .Zip(os.MostRecent(default(TRight)), resultSelector));
}
```